# getting error check ur mysql syntax near 'order(`pcode`)

Tags: php, mysql

i used `` for column name though im getting error...
my code is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order(`pcode`) VALUES ('$pcode')";

if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
die('cant connect ' .mysql_error());
```

Comment: Not directly related but you are exposing yourself to SQL injection. You should consider prepared statements and parametrized queries:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Also try upgrading to PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php, it is a much nicer extension for SQL, as the mysql extension is now deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)  for the "ORDER BY" clause
try

```
"INSERT INTO `order`(pcode) VALUES ('$pcode')";
```

Note: Please ensure $pcode is being run through [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or better yet look into the [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and their prepared queries

Comment: thnx .. it works.. im tryinf all possible ways using ` ` bt not used in table name.. big relief aftr two days

Answer (score 0):

if order is your table name and pcode is your column name then you can use this:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `order` (pcode) VALUES('%s')", $pcode);
```

Comment: The language is the language listed for the question, PHP, but sprintf is pretty universal